# POSTGRESQL ADD DATA WHITH PYTHON WITHOUT DUPLICATED

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, duplicates

I’m trying to  insert data in a POSTGRESQL  with a python script.

Before, i need to verify if the information don’t exist in the table.

I use the request below but i’have an error: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

Thanks for help

```
INSERT INTO data_brute_polluant 
VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) 
where not exists (
            select date_debut, code_st 
            from data_brute_pol 
            where  date_debut = data_brute_po.date_debut 
            AND code_st = data_brute_po.code_st);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't SHOUT.

Comment: Sorry, it’s for the title?

Comment: Yes, you typed it into a separate field for the title of your question. Stack Overflow _knows_ it's your title, and you may notice that Stack Overflow has formatted it prominently in large, bold type. The SHOUTING is unnecessary and annoying. Let SO format the title for you, and in the body of your question where you SHOUT about PostgresQL, either don't emphasize it at all (it's not necessary here IMO) or [use Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format it as _italic_ or, if you must, **bold**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want no duplicates on `date_debut` and `code_st`, then use a unique constraint or index:

```
alter table add constraint unq_data_brute_polluant 
    unique data_brute_polluant(date_debut, code_st);
```

Then use `on conflict`:

```
INSERT INTO data_brute_polluant 
    VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) 
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```